# Use CSS to style Web Notifications

Tags: css, web-notifications

I'd like to style web notifications with CSS. In the very least to be able to use `background`, `border` and `color` properties.

Note that I'm talking about actual *native web notifications*, not alternatives.

For those unaware of what web notifications are you can view the specification here...

http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/

Comment: Two questions for you: 1. Why do you think I'd want notifications from your website styled differently to all the other notifications my desktop environment generates? 2. If you want this feature in the web platform, why are you asking a question here instead of on a WHATWG or W3C mailing list?

Comment: This seems to go against the spirit of SO. If there is not a way to do something telling someone you will penalize them for explaining that is terrible.

Comment: You can set an icon, a title and a message, but you cannot use CSS to style them. Downvoted for threatening to downvote people for giving you an answer you don't want to hear.

Comment: @robertc One question for you: what makes you think this is intended for you? This is intended for my personal use.

Comment: I am a user of web technologies, you're asking a question about web technologies, it's a fairly normal assumption to make.  It being for your personal use won't make demanding web styling for non-web content any more useful.

Answer (score 11):

Notifications cannot be styled, period. They're explicitly meant to be *presentation independent*. They could be displayed in a thousand different ways; as desktop popup, as in-browser popup, as SMS notification, as line in a log file... you get the idea. You can provide the *content* of the notification, the *presentation* is entirely up to the presenting system.

Comment: Downvoting doesn't make it any less true. :-P